# How to fixed image on every screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I am looking for assistance on how to keep an image to fit the whole screen on any screen resolution. However the image is not the background. It is just a cover photo and when scrolling down once you will being to view website content. An example would be this website: http://riotdesign.eu/en/
I essentially am looking for the same idea.

Right now my div is set to these parameters. However the height of the image will stretch down farther whether i set to 100% or set px. Would it be easier to maybe have the content overlap the image at the bottom to hide it a bit? See below for css of div.

```
#cover{
width:100%;
height: 1000px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I resume your question, you are searching a '**Parallax Plugin jQuery**'

*Example: **[Simple Parallax Scrolling](http://pixelcog.com/parallax.js/)***

Comment: This could be very useful to me thank you very much Navid. One question: Is there any way to have the site content appear after one scroll on any resolution? In your example above depending on the resolution the content can be seen without scrolling down once.

Comment: Can you precise a little bit more pls ?

Comment: in the url I provided within the question, the 'grey back grounded' image will take up the entire screen no matter which resolution you view it on. That is the first thing I would like to achieve. Secondly, on that page, you can only view the rest of the content (white background with "Only good design, produced in Empoli (Florence)" title) if you scroll down and that applies again to any screen resolution you view on.

Answer (score 0):

You may use :

```
body {
   background : url("your/image/path") no-repeat center;
}
```

The problem seems to be : the div you are using does not cover the full size of your html document

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `position:fixed`:

```css
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}
.bgContainer, .bgContainer img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: fixed; 
}
```

```html
<div class='bgContainer'>
    <img src="http://www.psdgraphics.com/file/colorful-triangles-background.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/qq0xtnzk/)</kbd> for your convenience:

Comment: Hi Banana with fixed the image I will not be able to scroll with the page correct? I'm not necessarily looking to have it as a background but just a cover photo. I want it operating just as the link above, without the slider. thanks

Comment: @user3003228 you can scroll the page normally, jsut the image will remain fixed

Comment: understood, only wondering if you can have the image scroll up with the content, and the content start appearing after one scroll down?

Comment: Yep its possible. ALl you need to do is monitor the scroll event and show the items once they get into the viewport

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery to get the browser height on resize and then apply this height to the slideshow

```
$(window).height();
```

Here's a fiddle which changes the hight of a div to match the browser size http://jsfiddle.net/hxn9fe5b/